# Check if values of 2 different pandas dataframe fields are equal

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 separate pandas dataframes, one of which tracks whether the platform of a train station is free or not and another which tracks the movement of the trains (note I am only at proof-of-concept stage, I appreciate my code is not tidy).

Code is as below:

```
L = []
M = []
x = 0
for i in range(0,k*2): 
   L.append(0)
   M.append(x)
   if (i == k):
       x = 1

list_of_tuples = list(zip(M, L))  
blocks_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns = ['Direction', 'BlockTaken'])  

L = ["London Depot", "London Platform", "Birmingham Platform", "Crossover"]
M = [0,0,0,0]
list_of_tuples = list(zip(L, M))  

stations_control = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples, columns = ['Location', 'BlockTaken'])

for i in range (0,3600): 
    if (i%300==0): #Every 5 minutes, a new train enters service
        print("Train " + str(TrainNumber) + " leaving depot for " + str(train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'Start_Station'].iloc[0]) + " at " + str(t.time()) )
        
        train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'Dep'] = 'N'
        train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'Dep_Time'] = t.time()
        train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'From'] = L[0]
        train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'To'] = L[1]
        
        if(stations_control[train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'To']]['BlockTaken'] ==0):  
            print("Platform is free!!!")
        t = t + datetime.timedelta(0,300)
        #TrainNumber+=1
```

I know I am doing the if statement 4 lines from the end wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it properly. What I want to check is where the train is going and if the platform is free, print. What is the correct syntax here?

Comment: `if stations _control.loc[L[1], 'BlockTaken'] == 0:` ?...what exception is raised? Do you need a space betwee if and open parenthesis?

Comment: Hi Richie, thanks for your help. That gives me an error : KeyError: 'London Platform'

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

```py
b = train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'To'].iloc[0]
if(stations_control.loc[stations_control['Location']==b]['BlockTaken'] == 0):
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I get an error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: ```stations_control.loc[stations_control['Location']==b]['BlockTaken'].all() 
== 0 ```
or 
```
stations_control.loc[stations_control['Location']==b]['BlockTaken'][0] == 0
```

Comment: Can you show me the result of
```python
stations_control.loc[stations_control['Location']==b]['BlockTaken']
```

Comment: Name: BlockTaken, dtype: int64

Comment: and the output of train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'To'] ?

Comment: 0    London Platform
Name: To, dtype: object

Comment: Is my original code not runnable? I can add more to it if it isn't?

Comment: This is the code to select the right station 

```python
# this
stations_control[train_df...
# correct is
stations_control.loc[stations_control['Location']
```

Also you need to get this to return the station for the above code to work

```train_df.loc[train_df['Train_Number'] == TrainNumber, 'To']```

the desire output of this should be one of ["London Depot", "London Platform", "Birmingham Platform", "Crossover"]

Comment: Hi Yuki, I thank you so much for your help and assistance. I have just added the answer below. I was wanting to see if the platform is free and if it was to print out that it was free (I will be doing something more complex!). Thanks for your help and good luck as a new contributor!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. Thanks for the help guys.

```
if(stations_control.loc[stations_control['Location']==b].BlockTaken.iloc[0]== 0):
            print("Platform is free!!!")
```